# periodically onPurchasesUpdated not called, billing:6.0.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, billing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0s9o.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPtV1.png)

The error happens when purchasing with bank cards, also periodically, but when purchasing with a test card everything works every time.

What could be the reason? First of all is it ok to implement in this way? I am not listening to the purchases in any other screen because our app is a single device app